# Не могу скомпилировать проект в Visual Studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio-2015

Мне дали незнакомый проект.
При первой сборке проекта появилась эта ошибка  MSB8020 The build tools for Windows7.1SDK (Platform Toolset = 'Windows7.1SDK') cannot be found. To build using the Windows7.1SDK build tools, please install Windows7.1SDK build tools.  Alternatively, you may upgrade to the current Visual Studio tools by selecting the Project menu or right-click the solution, and then selecting "Retarget solution".   amcap   C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V140\Microsoft.Cpp.Platform.targets   57

У меня Visual Studio установлен на Win10.
Что мне необходимо доустановить, чтобы устранить данную ошибку?
Если возможно, то дайте ссылки для загрузки.

Comment: вам нужен перевод текста приведённого вами сообщения?

Comment: Зачем? Есть куча онлайн переводчиков :)

Comment: и как они переводят текст «Alternatively, you may upgrade to the current Visual Studio tools by selecting the Project menu or right-click the solution, and then selecting "Retarget solution"»?